# How to add a blank element at the first of any combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am retrieving a column from my mysql table and putting it in the combobox named company_name.But the problem is i am unable to keep the first element as blank.Here's the code:

How can I add a blank element as the first element of my combobox.....

```css
 string MyConnection = "datasource=localhost;database=lkpk;port=3306;username=root;password=11442145";
            MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
            Connection.Open();
            string query_company="select company_name from company";
            MySqlCommand command_company_name = new MySqlCommand(query_company,Connection);
            MySqlDataReader datareader_company = command_company_name.ExecuteReader();
            MySqlDataAdapter datadapter_company = new MySqlDataAdapter(query_company,Connection);
            DataSet dataset_company = new DataSet();
            datareader_company.Close();
            datadapter_company.Fill(dataset_company,"company");
            company_name.DataSource=dataset_company.Tables[0];
            company_name.DisplayMember="company_name";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Union All in select query to retrieve blank row. and same bind to combobox.

```
select '' as  company_name union all select company_name from company;
```